# Surround sound from stereo software

Tags: windows, audio, surround-sound, 5.1, voicemeeter

I just set a 5.1 surround setup on my Windows 11 PC only to find that most softwares do not support it and just output a stereo signal.

I'm currently using VoiceMeeter, which allows me to enable the UP MIX 6.1 mode under "Master section" and scale a stereo signal up to 6 channels.

The problem is that any sound coming from a channel different from left and right (in software that support surround sound) is discarded.

Is there a way to have VoiceMeeter (or any other application) only enable the UP MIX if no surround sound is coming in?

---

Edit:

I'm using front left and right speakers, a "subwoofer" (which is actually a normal speaker with a low pass filter) and two side speakers, all connected to [this USB soundcard](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07W21PGJQ). I do not have a center speaker at the moment.

The only difference is that my front left speaker is connected through HDMI, so I send the left channel to it separately via VoiceMeeter, but it is the same thing as if it were also connected to the soundcard.

Comment: What kind of 'surround setup"? How does it connect to the PC? What options do you see in the Speaker Setup?

Comment: @Tetsujin I updated my question

Comment: and just to be clear, you are NOT using spdif connection?

Comment: @Yorik no, I'm not. just analog 3.5 jacks and hdmi for my left speaker

Comment: if this is voicemeeter banana, then the manual references "macro buttons" which may be the way to go: setup a macro button to toggle between "passthrough" and matrix presets. page 37 ( https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/VoicemeeterBanana_UserManual.pdf ). I skimmed the document and don't see a way via the gui to query the type of source and do 1 thing if its 5.1 and another if it is stereo. They do have seem to have a remote API you can use also